# run GeneticSelectionCV on gpu python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gpu, genetic-algorithm

I train `GeneticSelectionCV` model on `cpu` with the following code:

```
from genetic_selection import GeneticSelectionCV
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
g = GeneticSelectionCV(estimator=GaussianNB(), scoring='accuracy').fit(X, y)
```

How can I train `GaussianNB` and `GeneticSelectionCV` on `GPU`?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-gpu-support

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of whether this has been tested, but you can likely use cuML's GPU-accelerated [GaussianNB](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/nightly/api.html#cuml.naive_bayes.GaussianNB) with `GeneticSelectionCV` as a drop-in replacement for scikit-learn's `GaussianNB`. [This recent blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/faster-text-classification-with-naive-bayes-and-gpus/) provides some information about potential performance.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. What about GeneticSelectionCV on GPU?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library this functionality comes from, but if that's something you'd be looking for you may want to file a feature request on that library's Github repository (if it's open-source and on Github).